# generating unique id(8 digits) for every user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my models.py is :

```
class clients(models.Model):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    '
    '
```

my serializers.py is:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = clients
        fields = ('client_identity_id','client_id','client_firstname','client_middlename','client_lastname','client_country','money','client_num')
        read_only_fields = ('money','client_id')
```

my views.py is:

```
def post(self,request):
        data=request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            client_A = clients.objects.get(client_identity_id=data['client_identity_id'])
            def create_unique_id():
                id=int(''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=8)))
                return id
            create_unique_id()
            unique = False
            while not unique:
                if not clients.objects.get(client_id=id):
                    unique = True
                else:
                    create_unique_id()
            client_A.client_id = id
            client_A.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when i make a post request it show me error "Field 'client_id' expected a number but got built-in function id" , what should i do ?
what i want is , when i make a post request it should generate an 8 digits unique id and save it,, and how can i generate an 8 length unique id contain letters and numbers ??

Answer (score 0):

Create one function somewhere in your project to generate unique  number and replace your model something like this and remove logic for generating id from views.

```
class clients(models.Model):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True, default=function_name)
    '
    '
```